# How to move documents to specific folders/sub folders based on 2 parts of the title

Tags: batch-file, command, directory, move

Newbie here,

Trying to clean up a filing headache.

I need a bat.file script to move files based on the beginning of the name and a certain word in the name. Sorry it is hard to explain. Here is my example....

```
195-21 Cat ate my shoe
-AP DISBURSEMENTS
-BILLING
-CLIENT PW

195-22 Jump on the Roof
-AP DISBURSEMENTS
-BILLING
-CLIENT PW

1104-03 Dog named Dave
-AP DISBURSEMENTS
-BILLING
-CLIENT PW

1010-146 Water for pond
-AP DISBURSEMENTS
-BILLING
-CLIENT PW
```

These are all .pdf files that I am looking to move:

```
195-21 December 2018 Invoice 59641
195-21 Amerson Report Class $84.61
195-22 December 2018 Invoice 57741
195-21 January 2018 Invoice 59131
1104-03 Ciox 18-Jun-16 $346.79
1104-08 St. Augustine 03-May-17 $35.21
1010-146 May 2018 Invoice 56981
```

So the file would move based on the number part of the name.

```
195-21 Cat ate my shoe
-AP DISBURSEMENTS
<------195-21 Amerson Report Class $84.61
-BILLING   
<---------195-21 December 2018 Invoice 59641
-CLIENT PW
```

If the word `Invoice` is in the file name I need it to go to `subfile Billing`. If not all others would need to go to the subfile `AP DISBURSEMENTS`.

If a main file doesn't exist for that number It can just stay where it is.

The problem is some of the numbers are more characters then others. `195-21` vs `1010-146`

ALSO I have no IDEA what I am doing. Its like I have this great plan but don't even know where to start to execute it...

Any and all help is appreciated!

I found this online and tried it. It was neat but again I don'd know what I am doing and this isnt what I was looking for.

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf') do (

    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder1=!filename1:~0,8!"
    mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
    move "!filename1!" "!folder1!" >nul
    endlocal

)
```

I would like the pdfs moved to its corresponding folder based on first part of name and "invoice" but this code doesn't do that. It moves them into folders based on the first few numbers. I have no clue what I am doing. Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: So only files containing `invoice` you want moved to `subfile Billing` ..? Do any of the numbers have relevance to your objective?

Comment: Yes the number at the beginning will determine which "main" folder it will go into. So 195-55 would go into the 195-55 folder and in there is would go into a subfolder- billing if it contained the word invoice. If it doesn't have the word invoice it would go into the 195-55 subfolder -AP Disbursments

Answer (score 0):

- You first should use a simple for to iterate the pdf files,
- a 2nd for /f to split the file names at the 1st space and
- a 3rd for /f to iterate the destination folder
- then check if it's an invoice and
- if the destination folder(s) exists.

That can all be done without delayedexpansion.

Sample tree before:

```
> tree \ /F
│
└───Base
    │   1010-146 May 2018 Invoice 56981.pdf
    │   1104-03 Ciox 18-Jun-16 $346.79.pdf
    │   1104-08 St. Augustine 03-May-17 $35.21.pdf
    │   195-21 Amerson Report Class $84.61.pdf
    │   195-21 December 2018 Invoice 59641.pdf
    │   195-21 January 2018 Invoice 59131.pdf
    │   195-22 December 2018 Invoice 57741.pdf
    │
    ├───1010-146 Water for pond
    │   ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
    │   ├───BILLING
    │   └───CLIENT PW
    ├───1104-03 Dog named Dave
    │   ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
    │   ├───BILLING
    │   └───CLIENT PW
    ├───195-21 Cat ate my shoe
    │   ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
    │   ├───BILLING
    │   └───CLIENT PW
    └───195-22 Jump on the Roof
        ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
        ├───BILLING
        └───CLIENT PW
```

running this batch file

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\10\SO_54136438.cmd
@Echo off
set "Base=A:\Base"
Set "Ext=*.pdf"
Set "DestInv=BILLING"
Set "DestDiv=AP DISBURSEMENTS"

For %%A in ("%Base%\%Ext%") Do For /f %%B in ("%%~nA") Do (
    For /F "delims=" %%C in ('Dir /B /AD "%Base%\%%B*" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Echo:Invoice|findstr /I "%%~nA" 1>Nul 2>&1 &&(
            If Not exist "%Base%\%%C\%DestInv%\" MD "%Base%\%%C\%DestInv%\"
            Move "%%~fA" "%Base%\%%C\%DestInv%\"
        )||(
            If Not exist "%Base%\%%C\%DestDiv%\" MD "%Base%\%%C\%DestDiv%\"
            Move "%%~fA" "%Base%\%%C\%DestDiv%\"
        )
    )
)
```

and after:

```
> tree \ /F
│
└───Base
    │   1104-08 St. Augustine 03-May-17 $35.21.pdf
    │
    ├───1010-146 Water for pond
    │   ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
    │   ├───BILLING
    │   │       1010-146 May 2018 Invoice 56981.pdf
    │   │
    │   └───CLIENT PW
    ├───1104-03 Dog named Dave
    │   ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
    │   │       1104-03 Ciox 18-Jun-16 $346.79.pdf
    │   │
    │   ├───BILLING
    │   └───CLIENT PW
    ├───195-21 Cat ate my shoe
    │   ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
    │   │       195-21 Amerson Report Class $84.61.pdf
    │   │
    │   ├───BILLING
    │   │       195-21 December 2018 Invoice 59641.pdf
    │   │       195-21 January 2018 Invoice 59131.pdf
    │   │
    │   └───CLIENT PW
    └───195-22 Jump on the Roof
        ├───AP DISBURSEMENTS
        ├───BILLING
        │       195-22 December 2018 Invoice 57741.pdf
        │
        └───CLIENT PW
```

Comment: Just set the variable `Base` to the directory containing your files and folders and you should be done.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I would like to accomplish. I will change the word base and give it a try. I will be in touch with results soon!

Comment: You did change `set "Base=A:\Base"` to the location of **YOUR** files and folders? I.E `set "Base=C:\Test"` or wherever you store them?

Comment: THAT WAS AMAZING! How can I thank you? Can I send a Thank you card?!

Comment: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) You need more rep for the voteup to be seen.